# IPv6 over BLE Using BLE dongles

Tags: bluetooth-lowenergy, ipv6

Recently I have been experimenting with IPv6 over BLE. I started by using a Raspberry PI, a Nordic semiconductor nrf51 device and sample code supplied by Nordic. I had no problems getting a COAP server up and running on the Nordic device and was able to access the server from the Raspberry PI using a COAP client.

My next step was to try and send data between two Raspberry PIs, using IPv6 over BLE.

To do this at the slave end:

1. sudo su
2. echo 1> /sys/kernel/debug/bluetooth/6lowpan_enable
3. hciconfig hci0 leadv

So at this stage the slave is advertising

At the master end

1. sudo su
2. echo 1> /sys/kernel/debug/bluetooth/6lowpan_enable
3. hcitool lescan
4. Make note of slave MAC address
5. echo "connect MAC address  1" > /sys/kernel/debug/bluetooth/6lowpan_control
6. ifconfig
7. Confirm existence of bt* interface
8. hcitool con
9. To confirm connection
10. ping6 -I bt* ff02::1

The above works for a short time and is quite unstable. Next I would like to send data back and forth from slave and master. At the master end, I have an interface which can be used to send data, but at the slave end I have nothing. I guess I need to set up a bt interface at the slave end, so data can be sent back and forth.

Any suggestions or recommendations would be appreciated.

Comment: More information:- The ping command is only works for the local bt* interface, and no response is received from the remote BLE device. This is not surprising since the remote/slave interface has not been set up to support 6lowpan yet. So the next step is to set up this up.

Comment: Did you figure this out?

Comment: No, unfortunate currently working on other things. Hope to get back to it perhaps next month.